# What's an insanely ballpark estimate for design & development of a big old intranet?

Tags: enterprise, portal, intranet

I work in a big organization, spread around the world, about 17,000 people. Have to ask for money wayyyyyy in advance for projects before even really knowing what they are.

So we're redesigning an old intranet. Spending a chunk of money we have on user research and UX design phase. More on the 1.0 and piloting it and dealing with content migration and all that fun stuff.

Any ideas (insane ballpark here) about how much $ to ask for the next phase (rolling it out, more testing, actually replacing the legacy intranet)? I know details are sparse but there are some silly budget deadlines that require me to pull a figure out of thin air before I even really know what our end users want. If I don't come up with a number, we get nothing and have to hunt around in various budgets to get cash.

What would you throw out for low / medium / high numbers here? Low being open source, out of the box functionality, not insane customization, no more UX research beyond what we're already doing, and off we go. Medium being a nicer step up, and high being paying someone like Igloo $400k to use their out of the box platform, and then another bunch of custom plugin development and design work on top of that.

Right now I'm thinking 250k, 500k, 750k. Am I in the right ballpark, or am I over in some other arena that's not even in the same league and hasn't seen a baseball game in years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've all but acknowledged, it's an impossible question to answer. You are constrained by an illogical system which seeks to reduce risk by increasing control in the mistaken belief that accounting for all spend in advance will increase return on investment. Your challenge is to learn how to play that system to your advantage, secure your funding and achieve the freedom to deliver your project with minimal interference.

**Support**

Fortunately, you are the best-placed person to do this. You have the best understanding of your organisational context and if you look at broadly similar (global, cross-functional) internal projects, you can get a good idea of how these projects are regarded and how they secure and maintain support and funding. Talk to colleagues and learn what you can. Ultimately you aren't looking for a right answer - you need to know what constitutes an acceptable answer and how to proceed when your guess proves to be "wrong".

Start looking externally to learn what you can about projects in similar organisations. Listening to others' experiences will give you a better understanding of potential risks, so dig deeper than the run-of-the-mill success stories. You might consider attending conferences, intranet-focused meetup groups and participating in online communities.

**Vision**

What is important is that you have a vision for your intranet project. As you go on, this vision may change. You will hear lots of assumptions about what people expect to be on the intranet. It's great to read you are conducting UX research as it's vital to understand what people actually need and use.

**Needs**

A guest presenter at a recent intranet event I ran showed us an intranet she'd built in-house over a five year period which was designed solely to help employees do their jobs effectively.

There were no generic calendar tools, no pages of content that no one ever looks at and no fashionable social features. Instead there was a lean, focused business tool, written in PHP, on which she'd spent **GBP20,000** each year.

Equivalent value? Probably a month of Sharepoint consultancy.

It takes careful leadership and communication, but once you stop trying to deliver mediocre generic solutions based on what everything thinks "should" be on an intranet, you can ditch out-of-the-box tools and start focusing on your users' real needs.